# Is this a VB.NET Arithmetic exception?

Tags: vb.net, exception, math

Okay, here is what I am asked to do by my teacher. Write a basic program that uses one of the arithmetic exceptions (other than dividing a number by zero) modeling the programs you’ve seen in this lesson. Then, in a second program, write one that would not produce an error.

The one's in the lesson were DivideByZeroException, NotFiniteNumberException, and OverflowException.

EDIT: I cannot use DivideByZeroException.

I am a beginner so I don't know much about programming. I'm taking a high school class, so please be patient.

Comment: I can't use the DivideByZeroException. If that is what you were referring to.

Comment: are you trying to create an exception, or just trying to write some code without an exception being thrown??

Comment: I am trying to create an Arithmetic Exception.

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry for all my nonsense. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bala's answer comes close:

```
Dim j As Integer = Integer.MaxValue + 1 '<-- doesn't compile
```

This would indeed overflow, but it doesn't compile because the compiler detects that we're trying to assign a value that doesn't fit inside an integer.

If we pass a variable to it, then the compiler doesn't make any assumption about the value of that variable, so the code compiles. It will fail with `OverflowException` at runtime.

```
Dim i As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
Dim j As Integer = i + 1 '<--  OverflowException at runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading the documentation on `ArithmeticException` here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arithmeticexception.aspx

There are 3 subclasses of ArithmeticException, which you can read about in the link above.

- `DivideByZeroException`
- `NotFiniteNumberException`
- `OverflowException`

The easiest one to produce is the DivideByZeroException - just divide an int by zero.  That might be a good one to try first.  For the other ones, read up on what causes them and try to create a scenario that matches the description.

Comment: AFAIK **NotFiniteNumberException** will not occur in C#, i believe the same to be applicable to vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim j As Integer = Integer.MaxValue + 1
```

that will cause `OverflowException`

Comment: Hey does this even compile ? i don't think so

Comment: Doesn't compile, but it's easy to fool the compiler: "Dim i As Integer = Integer.MaxValue", then "Dim j As Integer = i + 1"

Comment: @Meta-Knight Can you please post that as an answer so I can choose it as best answer?